# Understanding typecheck in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, macros

The following code is found from `include/linux/typecheck.h`:

```
/*
 * Check at compile time that something is of a particular type.
 * Always evaluates to 1 so you may use it easily in comparisons.
 */
#define typecheck(type,x) \
({  type __dummy; \
    typeof(x) __dummy2; \
    (void)(&__dummy == &__dummy2); \
    1;                                        \\ <---- Why here is a 1;?
})

/*
 * Check at compile time that 'function' is a certain type, or is a pointer
 * to that type (needs to use typedef for the function type.)
 */
#define typecheck_fn(type,function) \
({  typeof(type) __tmp = function; \
    (void)__tmp; \
})
```

Does the `1;` make any difference? Also, how can a block "evaluates to 1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro is a statement expression: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html

The value of the final expression is the value "returned" by the macro.

The `typecheck` macro causes a compile time warning if `x` is not of `type`.  Let's say I declared `char *a` and then tried `typecheck(char, a)` and compiled with `gcc -Wall`:

```
1.c: In function 'main':
1.c:5:21: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
     (void)(&__dummy == &__dummy2); \
                     ^
1.c:14:2: note: in expansion of macro 'typecheck'
  typecheck(char, a);
  ^
```